# Internal server error when deploying ARM Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am deploying an arm template that contains the following resources

```
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccount
Microsoft.Sql/servers
Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditPolicies
```

Now everything worked until I started changing the values for the `auditPolicies` object. Here are the steps I took until the `InternalServerError` occurred.

1. Added the `auditState` property and set its value to `Disabled`. Deployment Successful.
2. Changed the `auditState` property to `Enabled`. Deployment failed. Error states that the `storageAccountName` is required.
3. Added `storageAccountName` and set its value to the name of the storage account. Deployment failed. Error states that `storageAccountKey`.
4. Added `storageAccountKey` and set its value to `key1` of the storage account's `keys` object. Deployment failed. Internal Server Error - "An Error has occurred while saving Auditing settings, please try again later". Additionally, the errors cause the deployment to run indefinitely. Though I am not concerned about that aspect.

The following is the complete template.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "parameters": {
    "app-name-prefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "app-locations": {
      "type": "array",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "app-friendly-names": {
      "type": "array",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "db-user-admin-username": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "db-user-admin-password": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "database-audit-enabled": {
      "defaultValue": "Enabled",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Enabled",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storage-kind": {
      "defaultValue": "BlobStorage",
      "allowedValues": [
        "StorageV2",
        "BlobStorage"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storage-sku": {
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "db-service-name": "[concat(parameters('app-name-prefix'), '-database-service-')]",
    "storage-name": "[concat(toLower(parameters('app-name-prefix')), 'auditstorage')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(variables('storage-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()])]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storage-sku')]"
      },
      "kind": "[parameters('storage-kind')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "location": "[parameters('app-locations')[copyIndex()]]",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('app-locations'))]",
        "name": "storageCopy"
      },
      "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "accessTier": "Hot",
        "encryption": {
          "services": {
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "file": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "name": "[concat(variables('db-service-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()])]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('app-locations')[copyIndex()]]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "databaseServiceCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('app-locations'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('db-user-admin-username')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('db-user-admin-password')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "auditingPolicies",
          "name": "Default",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
          "location": "[parameters('app-locations')[copyIndex()]]",
          "properties": {
            "auditingState": "[parameters('database-audit-enabled')]",
            "storageAccountName": "[concat(variables('storage-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()])]",
            "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(concat(variables('storage-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()]), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value]"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', concat(variables('db-service-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()]))]",
            "storageCopy"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing that will help resolve this issue? What do I need to do to stop this internal server error?

---

I have added the complete template as was requested by @Pete

Comment: Could you rip out the parameters and paste the actual values so that I can recreate the error?

Comment: @pete there are no special values that would be revealed by supplying them. all are strings, except the auditingState value which is a boolean. ListKeys pulls the value out of my storage account and that value is meant to stay secret by design. but in essence it is an alphanumeric string. Additionally, before the properties were added to the auditing Policy object, this script works

Comment: Sure - but I just want to copy and paste the template to recreate the problem, I don't want to parse the functions out. It was 1:00am and I was too tired.

Comment: @pete I updated the question with the details you requested. I had left them out for brevity. Though I have also come to the proper solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after connecting with Azure Support.

The resource type: `Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingPolicies` is no longer supported and in the next few weeks Azure Resource Manager will no longer support this completely.

This resource type refers directly to table auditing, which has been reported as being deprecated for blob auditing. Though the documentation at this time does not directly report it. The docs will be updated in the coming days after this post, by the owners.

To enable the auditing you need to use the `Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings` object. The documentation on this is coming and until it does you will be directed to documentation for the database version of this resource type `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/auditingSettings`.

Auditing settings work much like the Auto-Tuning advisors. You can set either server or database level settings. The server settings will be inherited by the database if the database has not been configured directly.

This is a sample of the `auditingSettings` object that I use instead of the `auditingPolicies` object above. It is nested just the same.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
  "type": "auditingSettings",
  "name": "DefaultAuditingSettings",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', concat(variables('db-service-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()]))]",
    "storageCopy"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "state": "Enabled",
    "storageEndpoint": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', '/', variables('storage-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()]), '2018-02-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]",
    "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(concat(variables('storage-name'), parameters('app-friendly-names')[copyIndex()]), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value]",
    "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
    "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
    "retentionDays": "30"
  }
}
```